# Facebook photo does not appear when website link is shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My website has all the required Facebook meta tags in it and when I run it in the debugger it detects no errors, the og:image is fine and when I paste its link in the browser the image does appear, however when I/someone shared the link of the website the place in which the website image is supposed to show is white, and I don't mean blank but like there is the space of the image but it's blank instead of the supposed image.

And that's not all, when I post the link and Facebook auto fetched the info, the image does show up! but  once I click post, it turns white/blank.

The Facebook debugger tool shows that the og:image is fetched just fine.
Any ideas on what might be causing this?